# in asp.net web api, can I use HttpResponseException from any layer in my project?

Tags: asp.net, exception, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have a web api project that has a set of controllers that pass requests through a service layer, and logic layer and a repository layer, etc.

If an exception is thrown in a layer outside any controller (for example, the repository layer), if I throw an HttpResponseException, will that exception ultimately be passed back to the controller and be returned to the client?

Comment: Yes, why not? is an exception in the end (of course is not OK for exceptions to rich the client browser, only in debug mode).

Comment: I think, you can only use HttpResponseException controller to throw exception to client. you can not use this class any other NOT api layer. By using try catch and use HttpResponseException in controller to throw exception.